# Jquery Radiobutton validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <asp:RadioButton Text="Male" value="M" ID="rbM" runat="server" GroupName="g" />
    <asp:RadioButton Text="Female" value="F" ID="rbF" runat="server" GroupName="g" />
    <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" ID="btn" />
```

Here is my JS :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").click(function () {

                if ($("input[id='rbM']").is(":checked") == true) {
                alert($(this).next('label').text());

                }
                else if ($("input[id='rbF']").is(":checked") == true) {

                }
                else  {
                    alert("Please select an option!");
                }
            });

        });
```

It's a simple radiobutton validation. How to get the text here in the first two if conditions?I'm getting undefined in the alert of first if?

Comment: Where do you want to put the text?

Comment: You shouldn't use custom attributes like `Text`. Use a dataset attribute `data-text`.

Comment: hot to get the text here, what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

something like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        if ($("input[id='rbM']").is(":checked") == true) {
            console.log($("input[id='rbm']").attr('Text'))
        }
        else if ($("input[id='rbF']").is(":checked") == true) {
            console.log($("input[id='rbF']").attr('Text'))
        }
        else  {
            alert("Please select an option!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").click(function () {

        if ($("input[id='rbM']").is(":checked") == true) {

            alert($("input[id='rbM']").val());
        }
        else if ($("input[id='rbF']").is(":checked") == true) {
            alert($("input[id='rbF']").val());
        }
        else  {
            alert("Please select an option!");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
if ($("#rbM").is(":checked")) { // return true/false
} 
else  if ($("#rbF").is(":checked")) {
}
else {
  alert("Please select an option!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").click(function () {

                if ($("input[id='rbM']").is(":checked") == true) {

                    console.log($('#rbm').text());
                }
                else if ($("input[id='rbF']").is(":checked") == true) {
                    console.log($("#rbF").text())
                }
                else  {
                    alert("Please select an option!");
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a little more by getting the checked box directly like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var checkedValue = $('input[name="g"]:checked').val();
    if (checkedValue) {
        // ...process value
    } else {
        // Please select an option!
    }
});
```

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bFxga/3/).